# How to set the featured image / website thumbnail from my php code?

Tags: php, wordpress

I added a template php to my Wordpress site, showing a basketball image from url,  I'd like this to be the thumbnail of my website when sharing on social media

My php template-

```
<?php

/*
*Template Name: demo
*Template Post Type: post, page
*/

get_header();


$image = 'https://ff.com/basketball.jpg';
$imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($image));
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$imageData.'" alt=“image description” title=“image tooltip”>';
?>
```

When I load my website , I see a basketball image thanks to this template. But when I share my website I have no thumbnail

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what social media you're trying to show the thumbnail. Facebook uses open graph which would be something along these lines:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/02/19/arts/international/19iht-btnumbers19A/19iht-btnumbers19A-facebookJumbo-v2.jpg" />
```

Whereas twitter uses cards like so:

```
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/images/2012/02/19/us/19whitney-span/19whitney-span-articleLarge.jpg">
```

Here's a [blog post](https://www.takanomi.com/blog/ultimate-guide-to-social-meta-tags-open-graph-and-twitter-cards) explaining the details about it. Please note that you might need to meet certain image size requirements as well as additional meta tags in order to have the image picked up.